# Cannot install generated apk : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl562396072.tmp/base.apk

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am using Cake build tool to generate my apk (Xamarin project), the following is the script used to generate .apk file.

```
MSBuild(androidProject, settings =>
        settings.SetConfiguration(configuration)
        .WithTarget("SignAndroidPackage"));
```

The apk file is getting generated in the bin folder but I cannot install, the following error is shown

```
INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl562396072.tmp/base.apk
```

If anyone knows a solution, please share.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What JDK do you have installed?

Comment: I am using jdk1.8.0_172 and I see this error.